# Fancybox modifiy. How to modify fancybox to stop at last item on each gallery? (gallery 1 gallery 2 etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox plugin for my photo gallery. I have multiple galleries with more items (photos) and I want to know how to stop the slideshow when hits the last item on each gallery.  My fancybox.js was not modified. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Fancybox 1 or 2 and how are you calling in Fancybox?

Comment: Fancy box version  2

Comment: fancy box was not modified. It;s how it is standard

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the option `loop: false` when calling in fancybox.

You can read more about the options in [the fancybox docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: I did that, but it stops only at last item in gallery number five. But i want to stop at last item on each gallery ( i have 5 galleries)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve this issue so i post the answer: fancybox verifies  gallerys with data-fancybox-group and i put on earch gallery a different data-facybox-group "name: Ex:  gallery 1: "data-fancybox-group="thumb1"......
gallery 2: "data-fancybox-group="thumb2".....
gallery 3: "data-fancybox-group="thumb3"

It worked for me.